# Increase memory gradually while insert api response into core data in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am inserting the more than 20 thousands object in the core data by using the RestKitmap And also performing more than 4 thousands operations to fetch the data from the service by using operation queue(most of the services are repeatedly call for different user). After 1000 operations memory will reach in approx. 600MB , in the same way when in 1500 operation 800MB and gradually increase up-to 1.5GB when the operation queue operations reach to approx. 2500. At last we got the low memory and the app crashes before completing our operation queue

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you show client code of getOnlineSalesCompFromDate:to:withLsrId: ?